# Conference witholding reviewer feedback until registration - possible predatory conference?

Tags: peer-review, ethics, conference

I recently submitted a paper to a CS conference which was accepted after about ~2 weeks. Upon acceptance they notified me that reviewer feedback was withheld until registration was completed (~$490).

This seems quite predatory and a large red flag. I am fairly new to academia so my confidence is not absolute. Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not comment here on a specific conference. While withholding reviewer comments is unusual, in itself it is not a red flag or proof that the conference is predatory. If you submit a paper, you oblige yourself to attend the conference which means paying conference fees.

The short time to acceptance is however a "red flag" as is the wide-open call for papers. You can look at other conferences in the same line, look at some of the papers there and whether they are cited and you get a better idea whether this is a reasonable conference or not. You can also look at the sponsoring institution.

Comment: I find both the rapid acceptance and the withholding of reviews dubious….. especially the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Springer publishes their proceedings -- https://link.springer.com/conference/sai

I recommend looking at the editors of previous proceedings, citations from the proceedings, ..., to try to gauge the reputation of the conference series.